# Where can I get COVID test (for travel to US) in Budapest, Hungary?

Tags: usa, covid-19, hungary, budapest

The US requires a negative COVID test taken no more than 1 calendar day before the trip for entry. I'm going to travel to Budapest, Hungary (Dallas -> Frankfurt -> Budapest) and will return to the US in July.

Is there a list of test providers in Budapest that provide the required COVID test (accepted by US authorities) on any workday of the week where the result is available that same day?

Comment: The amount of covid testing locations at Budapest is just innumerable. Dozens and dozens of places, everywhere, they speak English and the prices are similar. Where are you going to be, which district?

Comment: It might well be that by the time you travel testing is no longer needed.

Comment: @Willeke Yes, that would be awesome, I read the news yesterday.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The US Embassy in Hungary's webpage](https://hu.usembassy.gov/covid-19/) under "COVID-19 Testing" lists local Hungarian providers who offer testing to travelers:

> **COVID-19 Testing:**
>
> Are PCR and/or antigen tests available for U.S. citizens in Hungary? Yes.
>
> If so, are test results reliably available within one calendar day? Yes.
>
> The providers below provide COVID-19 viral tests. The officially regulated price for the PCR test is 19,500 HUF. Antigen tests are offered at prices from 8,500 to 15,000 HUF. Some facilities offer express results for an additional fee.
>
> **Ferenc Liszt International Airport** – https://www.bud.hu/en/testing_center
>
> The airport’s coronavirus testing center is open 24 hours in Terminal 2B.
>
> Phone: +36-20-537-9300
>
> **First Med Center** – https://firstmedcenters.com/cov19test/
>
> Address: 1015 Budapest, Hattyú utca 14, 5th floor, Hattyúház
>
> Phone: +36-1-224-9090
>
> **Rozsakert Medical Center** – https://www.rmc.hu/en/specialities/covid-19
>
> Address: 1026 Budapest, Gábor Áron ut 74-78
>
> Phone: +36-1-392-0505
>
> **SYNLAB Diagnostic Centers** – https://www.synlab.com/coronavirus-tests
>
> COVID testing is available in Budapest, Kaposvár, Győr, Székesfehérvár, Dunaújváros, Kiskunhalas, Kecskemét, Miskolc, and Debrecen.
>
> Phone: +36-1-588-8500
>
> **Whitelab** – https://whitelab.hu/
>
> COVID testing is available in Budapest, Vác, Veszprém, Kaposvár, Győr, Szeged, Székesfehérvár, Dunaújváros, Kiskunhalas, Kecskemét, Miskolc, Esztergom, Pécs, Szombathely, Debrecen, etc.
>
> Phone: +36-70-362-0613

Answer (score 2):

> on any workday of the week where the result is available that same day?

Antigen test results typically arrive around 15 minutes after the test and are cheaper than PCR. Therefore any testing location performing antigen test will have same-day results.

Comment: I had an antigen test in Amsterdam last week from a large-scale (read: many locations) provider. After a brief wait, I was taken behind the curtain and given the test, the same swab-swish in reagent-drip onto a test trip process as the tests distributed by the US government. Then I walked back 10 minutes to where I was staying, and the email with my results was already waiting for me.